# Why can't we take input and manipulate it in one step?

Tags: c++, operators

Why is it acceptable to write the following code,

```
int x = foo();//some random value is assigned
cout << --x;
```

where `x` is mutated in the same line as output, but the code below is not?

```
int x = foo();//some random value is assigned
cin >> x--;
```

Is there another way to grab input and decrement it in one step?

Comment: For approximately the same reason that you can write `y = --x;` but not `x-- = y;`.  Nothing to do with input.

Comment: Unless you're entering an obfuscated coding contest - why would you want to?

Comment: Sure, why not? `cin >> x, x--;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in prefix increment and decrement operators return *lvalues*. The postfix increment and decrement operators return *prvalues*. The extractor operator for input streams (`operator>>()`) requires a modifiable lvalue as its operand.

**Built-in prefix operators:**

> ```c++
> A& operator++(A&)
> bool& operator++(bool&) (deprecated)
> P& operator++(P&)
> A& operator--(A&)
> P& operator--(P&)
> ```

**Built-in postfix operators:**

> ```c++
> A operator++(A&, int)
> bool operator++(bool&, int) (deprecated)
> P operator++(P&, int)
> A operator--(A&, int)
> P operator--(P&, int)
> ```

So this should compile:

```c++
std::cin >> --x;
```

but not this:

```c++
std::cin >> x--;
```

But the decrement will happen *before* the input is ever performed. You can't actually read into a variable and subsequent decrement its value in a single expression. You're better off just separating it into two:

```c++
std::cin >> x;
--x;
```

Comment: [Does not work for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bffc486130ea9b98). Or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: @BaummitAugen What doesn't work about that example? It looks to be doing what it should.

Comment: OP wants to "grab input and decrement it in one step". This just takes the input as is, doesn't it? There is not even any difference to `std::cin >> x`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The decrement is performed before the input from `std::cin` even starts, then the value of `x` is overwritten. He can't actually perform input then decrement all in one expression.

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote in my answer. I still do really understand what you mean by "this should work" since it is exactly equivalent to plain `std::cin >> x`. Well it compiles and runs without UB or such things. But  OP accepted your answer, so I guess I misunderstood the question and OP was trying to decrement before the read.

Comment: @BaummitAugen "It should work" is not very accurate. What I mean is that it won't produce an error or anything. I'll update the answer.

Comment: These built-in candidate functions for overload resolution purposes are deeply misleading. For example, postfix in-/decrement doesn't actually take a second argument. `--x;` also doesn't "return an lvalue reference"; it's just an lvalue.

Comment: @T.C. That two argument prefix operator *is* strange. I got it from cppreference. Do you think it's a typo?

Comment: @0x499602D2 You swapped postfix and prefix. The extra `int` in postfix operators is for disambiguation in operator overloading.

Comment: `bool& operator++(bool&) (deprecated)` What is this? What does it mean?

Comment: @NeilKirk It was copied from here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_postfix_operators